# Is it possible to change a key to mean a function in java?

Tags: function, hotkeys, registerhotkey

In java and other languages, % is used for modulus. Is there a way to set a symbol, say "~" to mean a function, for instance factorial? So if you type ~15, it would compute 15!

Comment: No, you can't define your own operators in Java. (`%` is not a *key*; it's a *character* (ASCII character 0x25 (37 decimal)), and it represents the modulus *operator* in code.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a **symbol** to a `function` like what you want in **Java**, because other symbol like as you said is `Operator` symbols which is use to get something in an equation or a logical situation which is predefined in Java itself.